# How to Fix IE 11 Error When Forcing https in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I recently redirected all traffic from http to https using htaccess. I also did set it to https://www.example.com/ in Admin > Settings.

On Chrome and Firefox, everything works well but on IE11/Win8.1 I get a "This page can’t be displayed".

Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is anybody having the same issue?

Comment: Are you using SSL 2.0 and TLS 1.2 together? See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2851628

Comment: @Roy Did that already. Went as far as to tick only TLS 1.2 and untick everything else.